# How do I make a Radio Widget look like a button

Tags: flutter, radio-button, flutter-layout

Im rebuilding an old app and need to make radio buttons look like actual buttons.
Whats the best way to do this?

Old app reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a stateful widget and keep track of a selected value in that widget. The widget will be a container, with child Text. When tapped you change the selected value. Then based on the selected value you return a different BoxDecoration for your container. See Below for code:

```
class ButtonStyleRadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
 // Function to call when tapped
 Function(bool) onChanged;

 ButtonStyleRadioButton({this.onChanged});

_ButtonStyleRadioButtonState createState() => _ButtonStyleRadioButtonState();
}

class _ButtonStyleRadioButtonState extends State<ButtonStyleRadioButton> {
  bool _selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){ setState(() {
       _selected = !_selected; 
       // Callback to passed in function
       widget.onChanged(_selected);
      });},
      child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child:  Text('Consumer'),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
         border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
         color: _selected ? Colors.red : Colors.white
       )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this make sense. Then in the parent state holding the `GridView` with our `ButtonStyleRadioButton` we have to pass a callback to each button, that when called, returns its new value.
Then we use this new value to disable all `ButtonStyleRadioButton` except the caller and update the state of any previously selected `ButtonStyleRadioButton`.
Does this make sense or is there a way to use the already implemented `Radio` Widget logic and apply it to our `ButtonStyledRadioButton`?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JoelBroström you just pass in a function that takes a bool as a parameter and then call itin the onTap method. I added the code for that to my answer. Let the widget manage it's own state, you don't have to do it. If you want you can make it stateless and pass in the "selected" value as well then you won't need any state. But I find this way better for myself personally.